# Recommended workflow for previewing a PSD (Win) in an iPhone

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow, mobile, ios, proofing

I'm looking for an app that would allow me to simply view my PSD on my iphone as I'm creating it. Something like this exists for Mac ([LiveView](http://zambetti.com/projects/liveview/) and [Skala Preview](http://bjango.com/mac/skalapreview/)), but I can't find anything similar for Windows.

If nothing exists, **what yould you recommend as a workflow to allow me to quickly view my psd's on my iphone as I'm creating them?**

(P.S. Remember when people use to complain about the limited software options for mac?)

Comment: Did you check PSD viewer?: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/psd-viewer-for-photoshop/id418319722?mt=8

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I did see that. I'd have to email every little change to my self and even then the app is pretty bad. I do appreciate the response though, this has been a pretty quiet thread.

Comment: Well, it's a very specific need, and I don't think any of us has come across the situation before (maybe because iPhone user = generally apple user). But the workflow part of the question would be the one I would highlight to get more (any) responses. Do you mind if I edit it? You can revert the changes if they don't represent your problem.

Comment: Edited, it will also appear in the top. If there are still no solutions we can add a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox does have the ability view PSD files within the iOS app. It won't allow you to do anything with them, but at very least you'd be able to see your updates from the desktop synced to your phone.